# why the spring ioc + struts 2 not work after add spring security 3 support

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security, web.xml

After I add the following into web.xml to support spring security 3. the spring ioc + struts2 not work, when struts2 point to a bean, system can not search the bean definition in applicationContext.xml, it just shows me Class Not Defined

```
<context-param>
     <!-- Defines definition file for security setting. -->
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>classpath:app-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Bootstraps the Spring root web application context before servlet initialization -->
    <!-- The following code defines filter for Spring Security -->
    <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Please help! thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you forgot to add some JARs that are needed.  Make sure that you (and the classloader) can find the class that it says is missing.  (Hint: It's probably one of the Spring security JARs.)

Comment: but if I remove those configuration in web.xml, everything works well.So it won't be the problem of jar missing

Comment: can you list the spring* jars on your classpath? are you using any kind of a dependency management system? (eg Maven/Ivy)

Comment: No, we just include all *.jar in build path, if it's the jar's problem, then once i remove the configuration in web.xml, it should not work, right ? but actually it works!